# How can I make an unique symbol when I have more than one element in the same coordinate?

Tags: qgis, symbology, element

I'm trying to map in QGIS with symbols. I'm georeferencing fruits in the same point. For example in a same place (equal coordinate) I have identified three different fruits. So in my Excel I have three rows with the same coordinates but each row has a different fruit.

What I want to do is to make an unique symbol when I have more than one fruit. I think that I need to use a conditional. I dont know how to continue.

Comment: I suggest you run `join attributes by location` with this one layer as both inputs, then `delete duplicate geometries`, then you should have single points with maybe multiple attributes which you can base your condition on then.

Answer (score 4):

Use different symbol layers for each symbol you want to use, then set a condition for visibility based on how many points are in the same place. Let's say you want to create a symbology like this: 1 point in the same place = red dot; 2 points in the same place = blue square; 3 points in the same place = green triangle.

Set a condition for each symbol layer. For the symbol to be shown when you have two points in the same place, click `Enable symbol layer / Data driven override / Edit...` and paste the following expression:

```
array_length(overlay_nearest('point', $id, limit:=-1))=1
```

For symbols where three points are in the same place, replace `=1` at the end of the expression with `=2`. The expression evaluates how many points are in the same location as the current point. Based on that, the symbol layer shows up or not.

*Screenshot: the labels show how many points are in the same place: red=1, blue=2, green=3:*
[image]